# Create condition for key of type string for object

Tags: typescript

I want to create a function to sort an entity list. You should be able to sort any type of object (first argument) and the second parameter should be a key of the entity type of type string because I compare using `localCompare`

I was able to create this snippet that is working but the thing is I have to add `as string` on `keyA` and `keyB` or else there are evaluated as `T[KeyWithStringValue<T>]` and not as string. And by definition I feel like `T[KeyWithStringValue<T>] == string`

Is there some better way to do this ?

```
type PickByValue<T, ValueType> = { [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends ValueType ? Key : never }[keyof T];

type KeyWithStringValue<T> = PickByValue<T, string>;

export const sortEntityBy = <T>(entities: T[], key: KeyWithStringValue<T>): T[] => {
  if (!entities) return [];
  const sorted = [...entities];
  return sorted.sort((a, b) => {
    const keyA = a[key] as string;
    const keyB = b[key] as string;
    return keyA.localeCompare(keyB);
  });
};
```

The current snippet is working as expected for example:

```
type Country = {
  name: string;
  iso: string;
  id: number;
}

type CountryTypeString = KeyWithStringValue<Country>;

//CountryTypeString == "name" | "iso"
```

Here is a [typescript sandbox reproducing the issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBACglgYwNYCEQDUCGAbArhAHgBUAaKLPCI8CAPigF4oBvKAbQGkIQo4A7KEm4B7AGZQiAXQBcEzt0lQIAD2AQ+AEwDO5HPmqQoAfihcesvhABuEAE5QAvmyEgxEyQG4AUKENmA6nDAABYAysC2-ADmFPjE9EzwyGixhKRQWhHRtN5eCMJ8mRnCtsAAonzAQSBojFDxABTqVVUQWrJEbJJkLrIBQWFZfDF6abQAlB1djPTMXlC84g0AhM1BcG3jULYQwLi2Al3eC-mFwMWlEBp1bAB092utWp7z27v7Alolahq3X6UNBqYMgAIy2DFmrxOBSKLgAgnVMM4FMcFlBTrDuCg6iDkSAXmi3nsDoJuHDbthhAgcBAAMLCAC2YEwOwaLhQ41RDk5XgcuV80HpuEqth4TDmCzgGgsuAZILsqL4mAZEFkmUiw1RcC+aqGUW8Di8eRh53ywqybVkQpFIGmTCORox53+P2tFp0TBdFRaNRADTNIo2WjIACJtcIQ+MvEA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By mixing my first solution with @wonderflame proposition I got the best of both world

```
type PickByValue<T, ValueType> = { [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends ValueType ? Key : never }[keyof T];

type KeyWithStringValue<T> = PickByValue<T, string>;

export const sortEntityBy = <T extends { [key in K]: string}, K extends KeyWithStringValue<T>>(entities: T[], key: K): T[] => {
  if (!entities) return [];
  const sorted = [...entities];
  return sorted.sort((a, b) => a[key].localeCompare(b[key]));
};

type Country = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  iso: string;
}

const countries: Country[] = [];

const sortedCountries = sortEntityBy(countries, "name")
```

when using sortEntityBy the `key` gets autocompleted as key properties that have string value, and now the function code understand that T[K] is of string type

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier approach without a generic type to find a key. Just declare  the `key` as the key of the `T` and `T` must be an object with key `K` and value `string`:

```
const sortEntityBy = <T extends Record<K, string>, K extends keyof T>(
  entities: T[],
  key: K,
): T[] => {}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBBICcoFExQJZQJ4CEswF4YAeAFRgFMAPKCsAEwhgCULQF7iBpAGjigTowAcwB8fLpRp1GMANYUsIAGYxSogBQAoGJTSZ0FCAC41AbQC6PHfMWneWgJSnSlwqJgBvG+lUaAhHQYGEaOMAgUUACuCGAwlgDcNqCQsPBIFPSE8QB0eUEGRhZJuhHRsXCItPQ56VAaGgCGfABGYQQe3rq6KdC2WACC2Y1mCljFNj3gfWM42S2jihPd4ZExcWMDOQA2IMCN2xQAwiAAtgAOjREas44lMAC+d1oPSVrY5xQwJ1FoCPhELowdD0UxgKKnFoUBD3MCNU4UUzQQQie7oeBIgRCYRJV5aLS9WCgX5YoymH5-LBuIiJfGEyoZegU0lMIh1VDBXBYDTEv6GCB8ADk6JAgueQA)

Comment: Oh thanks I see what you did there, it's still  not exactly what I want because I lose the autocomplete now

I can do `sortEntityBy(countries, '')` and the empty string can autocomplete to id, iso or name but I get an error if I use id

Comment: got it, you can check it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdgGxAZWAJwJZwOYGkIgDOAPACoB8UAvFANYED2AZlAN4BQUUA2rlFnUYtSUAIaEopXgF0oEAB7AIcACYTC6LNigB+KHwBcUOBABuENNKNTc0gNzsAvg-YBjBnA1RCDNMACicMAYoABCINRQZHKKympQAEoQ7mgqxLgANN6aOORZfApKqhLwSKiYOPhEZOTkABScckEhGBCE1tzSGY30IEaZ7ACUHbJUlBxcGCx1AITKwcFtg1BoEMAArmhwPPaN7p7A3r5KKpHcAHSX8y1tu1yrG1tHfhAq5z5+dXWiWQBGy2M2I0uPsvL0AIKRUTcXp3LhQUGHXqhSK-GEEOH3NabbYQ84IBiuUQICAAYQYAFswKJVnVkYMHFxHAynC5QJAoOT1kE0BEaBN+CojHB1hTfhZGcZRBSIEYNBVsJKMD45TlFaz2G4PF53NzNG0jFyeSBOmddlqDs8Tkb9RIaB8As0wiA6rqea1CFkAOTKhhellAA)